# Update Pandas series based on condition in a separate series

Tags: python, pandas

All,

I would like to update an existing column in pandas. Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'], 'b': ['C', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'c': np.random.randn(4), 'd': np.random.randn(4) })

df['NewColumn1'] = np.where( df['a'].str.contains('A') & df['b'].str.contains('C') , df['c'], 1)

df
   a  b         c         d  NewColumn1
0  A  C -0.668001 -0.434521   -0.668001
1  B  A  1.893248  1.927666    1.000000
2  C  B -2.145310  0.602808    1.000000
3  A  C  0.323770  0.966303    0.323770
```

I have create a new column called 'NewColumn1'.

Now I would like to update NewColumn1 based on new condition (my aim here is to update NewColumn1 not overwrite its previous values).

I would like to update 'NewColumn1' and set its values to 100 when column 'd' is bigger than 1. How can I do that?

Many Thanks

Comment: Do you want `df['c'] = np.where( df['a'].str.contains('A') & df['b'].str.contains('C') , df['c'], 1) ?
`

Comment: Do you need assign to `c` column instead `NewColumn` ?

Comment: @jezrael  no this is not  what I need :)  maybe I misunderstood your example. let me edit

Comment: sorry jezrael i got you confused. I have amended my example accordingly. Hopefully this time it is clearer. Thank you

Comment: @jpp df['NewColumn'] is not equal to df['c']

Comment: @jezrael   yes i need to assign column 'NewColumn' (i would like to update it but not overwrite my first assignment)

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand.

Comment: @jezrael  i have updated my example. Hopefully i made it clearer

Comment: Do you think `df['NewColumn1'] = np.where( df['d'] > 1 , 100, df['NewColumn1'])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.loc` accessor to update an existing series:

```
df.loc[df['d'] > 1, 'NewColumn1'] = 100
```

Your question is still unclear: "Update but not overwrite previous values" does not make sense.

In future, provide your *desired output*. This is much more valuable than a lengthy description.

Comment: sorry that was not intentional i was trying to be as clear as possible. May I ask  can the condition df['d']>1  be extended to multiple conditions somehting similar to this:  df.loc[df['d'] > 1 & df['c']<1, 'NewColumn1'] = 100

Comment: Yes, try this: `df.loc[(df['d'] > 1) & (df['c'] < 1), 'NewColumn1'] = 100`

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
df['NewColumn1'] = np.where( df['d'] > 1 , 100, df['NewColumn1'])
```